# Is Three some sort of priest?

Tags: hamatora

On episode 9, we learn a bit about Three's past and the fact that he was a mercenary.
I noticed that in the flashbacks, he dressed differently than the way he dresses in the present time.
In the present time, he seems to be dressed as a priest of some sort. He even carries a Bible to activate his Minimum.

[image: Three's present time style!]

Since he quit being a mercenary because he ended up causing the death of a bunch of orphans, I was wondering if Three became some sort of clergyman.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say he was not a priest, although this may still be proven wrong since Season 2 has not come out. From Hamatora's wiki, I was only able to find out this much information...

> He once planted a bomb to destroy his enemies in HQ which resulted in him accidentally blowing up some of the orphans he looked over. With extreme guilt, he felt that he should raise the kids to kill him.

I believe the bible is meant to reflect on his guilt over the killings of the orphans, based on the fact that...

> Three has the power to unleash his inner beast by holding a Bible and asking the Lord for forgiveness. By doing this, he becomes extremely strong.

I believe the true intent of this is to show Three's guilt for his actions by using the bible as a vector.